# JWT Authentication, expired tokens still work unless setting ClockSkew

Tags: .net, jwt

I had a problem where my expired tokens (which had a lifetime of 20 seconds) could still work for about 4-5 minutes, after spending time researching it I found it's because ClockSkew is by default set to 5 minutes, after I set it to 0, there was no other problem.

I want my jwt to have a lifetime between 1 to 5 minutes and have a refresh token which lasts for a few weeks, therefore, the jwt is constantly refreshed.
But I want to know, why is ClockSkew set to 5 minutes (I assume that's the value). And since I changed it to 0, what can it cause to go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One useful situation for the ClockSkew is when you have 2 authentication servers, how do you know they are in sync? what happens if the first one says its not expired and then second expired? this is obviously going to cause problem. So it usually set taking into account the timing of multiple Authentication servers.

A nice explanation of this is here:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/245173/how-much-time-should-you-allow-for-clock-skew/245182#245182

If you are simply using 1 authentication server( which is most cases ) this will not cause any problems, and will make your life easier when testing as you don't have to wait potentially 5 mins every time.